# Brownie "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)."

Tags: python

I'm using Brownie to learn about programming in general and smart contracts. When I've written a contract and go to compile it I do not receive a `.json` file in the `"build" folder`.

When using the `brownie compile` command this is what's returned in the terminal:

`"PS C:\Users\Brian Lee\.brownie\Brian folder> brownie compile INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). Brownie v1.14.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum Project has been compiled. Build artifacts saved at C:\Users\Brian Lee\.brownie\Brian folder\build\contracts PS C:\Users\Brian Lee\.brownie\Brian folder> "`

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there is no contract object in your code so there's nothing for brownie to compile.

Comment: 'INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).' is displayed even with the fresh project. This message is shown even with a simple 'brownie' command.